# Style Transfer in CoreML

Tags: ios, neural-network, coreml

I would like to use style transfer ([example](https://github.com/jcjohnson/fast-neural-style)) in CoreML. Since CoreML support converting Keras my first thought was to convert one of their samples like this [one](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/neural_style_transfer.py) or this [one](https://github.com/titu1994/Neural-Style-Transfer) but it seems there's few issue with this approach based on [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80210) thread.

How can I use Style Transfer in CoreML? any examples will help.

Edit:

- Thanks for the [link](https://github.com/eelretep/mlmodelzoo) @twerdster, I was able to test it and it's working for me.
- Additionally I found this ([torch2coreml](https://github.com/prisma-ai/torch2coreml/)) repo by Prisma.

Comment: Not all layer types are supported by the Core ML model format, especially not custom layer types. In this case it looks like ReflectionPadding2 is not something that Core ML understands, and so you cannot use this model with Core ML.

Comment: Is it not supported by Core ML, or not supported by the conversion form coremltools? Where do you find references on what CoreML supports?

Comment: The .mlmodel file format is documented by Apple. (You can download the docs from the coremltools page.) Since Core ML only supports specific layer types, it won't understand anything "custom" or created with a Keras lambda layer -- since that could literally be _anything_. If Core ML does not support what you want to do, then one option is to go a level deeper and implement the neural net in Metal.

Comment: Try this git repo: https://github.com/eelretep/mlmodelzoo

Comment: This person copied and pasted my question. `/Volumes/SSD/Users/jeshua` is my volume!

Comment: @JeshuaLacock hey Jeshua, this person has a name = 'jimmy', Additionally I was highlighting the issue using the public thread which happen to be yours as an example, I even linked back to it not like I claimed it's mine.

Comment: Well Jimmy, that is still plagiarism. In this question you state that *you* where trying to convert models, so why wouldn't you just use your own output?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock that was not my intention, I could've worded the question better to show that you are the owner of the error message . I have reworded the question and removed your error message. I might have asked similar question to yours but I truly believe I didn't just "copy pasted" your question, hopefully this will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's `Create ML` app to make your own styles. It is super easy to use. I learned it in few hours. You need:

1. Training style image
2. Validation image (just to see how style performs with each iteration)
3. Set of content images (say 500)

[image]

[image]

Code to make a style transfer (`allSabilandStylesParameterIn` == `"image"`, `allSabilandStylesParameterOut` == `"stylizedImage"`):

```
import CoreML
import Vision

private static func makeCreateNextMLSabilandStyle(
        input: UIImage,
        style: String
    ) -> UIImage
    {
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: style, ofType: "mlmodelc")
        else { return input }
        
        let u = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
        
        // 1
        guard
            let mlModel = try? MLModel(contentsOf: u)
        else {
            return input
        }
        // 2
        let imageOptions: [MLFeatureValue.ImageOption: Any] = [
            .cropAndScale: VNImageCropAndScaleOption.scaleFill.rawValue
        ]
        guard
            let cgImage = input.cgImage,
            let imageConstraint = mlModel.modelDescription.inputDescriptionsByName[allSabilandStylesParameterIn[style]!]?.imageConstraint,
            let inputImg = try? MLFeatureValue(cgImage: cgImage, constraint: imageConstraint, options: imageOptions),
            let inputImage = try? MLDictionaryFeatureProvider(dictionary: [allSabilandStylesParameterIn[style]!: inputImg])
        else {
            return input
        }
        // 3
        guard
            let stylizedImage = try? mlModel.prediction(from: inputImage),
            let imgBuffer = stylizedImage.featureValue(for: allSabilandStylesParameterOut[style]!)?.imageBufferValue
        else {
            return input
        }
        
        if let stylized = UIImage(withCVImageBuffer: imgBuffer)
        {
            return stylized
        }
        else
        {
            return input
        }
    }
```

And `UIImage` extension:

```
    // https://www.jianshu.com/p/d068cdf37d03
    convenience init?(withCVImageBuffer cvImageBuffer: CVImageBuffer) {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: cvImageBuffer)
        let context = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        guard
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
```